# How to get a working wikitable in a nested tabber?

Tags: nested, wiki

When I place a wikitable in a nested tab on a wikipage, the wikitable seems to break the processing of the tabs and itself. Explanatory image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gVtz.jpg.

In the explanatory image you see a nested tab called 'Slayer shops' in the tab 'Merching: collection and conversion'. There is supposed to be a wikitable in the nested tab 'Slayer shops', but instead you see some preceding text which stops at '{' (which is the start of the wikitable code). Furthermore, there are supposed to be multiple tabs after the nested tab 'Slayer shops', but they are also gone.

I was wondering if anybody knows a solution to this problem?

Kind regards,

Jan

---

The outer tabs are made through:

```
<tabber>Outer tab title 1=
Content outer tab 1
|-|Outer tab title 2=
Content outer tab 2
</tabber>
```

The inner tabs are added through:

```
<tabber>Outer tab title 1=
   Content outer tab 1
      {{#tag:tabber|Inner tab title 1=
         Content outer tab 1, inner tab 1
      {{!}}-{{!}}Inner tab title 2=
         Content outer tab 1, inner tab 2
      }}
|-|Outer tab title 2=
   Content outer tab 2
      {{#tag:tabber|Inner tab title 1=
         Content outer tab 2, inner tab 1
      {{!}}-{{!}}Inner tab title 2=
         Content outer tab 2, inner tab 2
      }}
</tabber>
```

The problem arises when wikitables are placed in the content of inner tabs:

```
<tabber>Outer tab title 1=
   Content outer tab 1
      {{#tag:tabber|Inner tab title 1=
         Content outer tab 1, inner tab 1
         {|class="wikitable sortable" 
         !Column title 1
         !Column title 2

         |-
         |Element column 1, row 1
         |Element column 2, row 1
         |-
         |Element column 1, row 2
         |Element column 2, row 2
         |}
      {{!}}-{{!}}Inner tab title 2=
         Content outer tab 1, inner tab 2
         {|class="wikitable sortable" 
         !Column title 1
         !Column title 2

         |-
         |Element column 1, row 1
         |Element column 2, row 1
         |-
         |Element column 1, row 2
         |Element column 2, row 2
         |}
      }}
|-|Outer tab title 2=
   Content outer tab 2
      {{#tag:tabber|Inner tab title 1=
         Content outer tab 2, inner tab 1
         {|class="wikitable sortable" 
         !Column title 1
         !Column title 2

         |-
         |Element column 1, row 1
         |Element column 2, row 1
         |-
         |Element column 1, row 2
         |Element column 2, row 2
         |}
      {{!}}-{{!}}Inner tab title 2=
         Content outer tab 2, inner tab 2
         {|class="wikitable sortable" 
         !Column title 1
         !Column title 2

         |-
         |Element column 1, row 1
         |Element column 2, row 1
         |-
         |Element column 1, row 2
         |Element column 2, row 2
         |}
      }}
</tabber>
```

The previous code results in: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKflx.jpg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you have to replace `|` with `{{!}}` in the tables!